# Recursive SQL with 1:n relation to another table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a problem that is giving me a headache:

We work with T-SQL (MS SQL-Server).
I have a ragged parent/child hierachy in one table. Each row in the table with the parent/child relation (T1) has multiple values in another table (T2).
My goal is to get the values from table T2 for each row of table T1, inluding those of it's ancenstors.

Here is an example:

T1 has the ragged parent child hierarchy.

```
     ClassID            |     ParentclassID     
    ____________________|___________________________
    1                   |     NULL              
    --------------------|---------------------------
    2                   |     1
    --------------------|---------------------------
    3                   |     2
     -------------------|---------------------------
    4                   |     1
```

T2 has multiple values for each of the values from table T1

```
       ClassID          |       FeatureID       
    ____________________|___________________________
    1                   |      A                
    --------------------|---------------------------
    1                   |      B
    --------------------|---------------------------
    2                   |      C
    --------------------|---------------------------
    2                   |      D
    --------------------|---------------------------
    3                   |      E       
    --------------------|---------------------------
    4                   |      F
```

My goal is the following Output:

```
    ClassID             |       FeatureID       
    ____________________|___________________________
    1                   |      A                
    --------------------|---------------------------
    1                   |      B
    --------------------|---------------------------
    2                   |      A
    --------------------|---------------------------
    2                   |      B
    --------------------|---------------------------        
    2                   |      C
    --------------------|---------------------------
    2                   |      D
    --------------------|---------------------------
    3                   |      A
    --------------------|---------------------------
    3                   |      B
    --------------------|---------------------------        
    3                   |      C
    --------------------|---------------------------
    3                   |      D
    --------------------|---------------------------        
    3                   |      E       
    --------------------|---------------------------
    4                   |      A     
    --------------------|---------------------------
    4                   |      B     
    --------------------|---------------------------
    4                   |      F
```

If it would only be the ragged hierarchy, I could solve this with an recursive cte. But it is the 1:n relation to the table T2 that is causing the problems.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You could use a `hierarchyid` field and get rid of the CTE. *With* the CTE you'll have to join with the feature table in all parts. I *think* this is related to the BOM explosion problem. Perhaps you should google for `T-SQL BOM`. There may be better solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join on tree

```
declare @H table (id int primary key, par int);
insert into @H values 
       (1, NULL)              
     , (2, 1)
     , (3, 2)
     , (4, 1);
DECLARE @Feature AS TABLE
(
    ClassID int,
    FeatureID char(1)
)
INSERT INTO @Feature (ClassID, FeatureID) VALUES
(1, 'A'), (1, 'B'),
(2, 'C'), (2, 'D'),
(3, 'E'), 
(4, 'F'),
(5, 'G');
with cte as 
(  select h.id,   h.par,   h.id as tree 
   from @H h
   union all 
   select cte.id, cte.par, h.par
   from cte 
   join @H H 
     on cte.tree = h.id
)
select * from cte 
join @Feature f 
  on f.ClassID = cte.tree
where cte.tree is not null
order by cte.id, cte.par, cte.tree
```

Comment: I knew my answer was over complicated... +1

Comment: Perfect - thank you so much. Very elegant and flexible solution, just what I was looking for.